# SFTP - check and copy recent files to local then archive within sftp

Tags: linux, shell-script, sftp

We have application integration layer over SFTP where the file feeds placed in SFTP server on random time interval like every 10 minute or 30 min interval and our need is to copy files from SFTP path to local,  after complete of file copy to local then move those copied files to Archive directory in sftp server

currently using expect method to copy the files via cronjob but below script is not sufficient for actual need above mentioned. Please help to enhance this script or with other options, struggling with minimal knowledge of scripting

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sftp test_user@sftpserver.com
expect "password:"
send "12345\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /incoming\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget -a *.xml /path_to_local_server\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

Does except method SFTP connection will get timeout?

Comment: don't use password authentication for sftp.  set up public key auth instead. it's more secure and you won't need to write an expect script just to fetch a file.

Comment: Hi Cas, Thank you.. yes we will do SSH key based auth for connection but struggling to copy files to local then moved copied to archive folder in sftp